# Assign focus to a UITextField during Validation

Tags: objective-c, validation, ios5, uitextfield

I have a method, -(void)validateFormInput:(UITextField *)textField that gets called when the form's "submit" button is pressed. The method does the following:

1) Validates text in a given textField
2) If invalid, pops up an alert box, draws a red border around the UITextField and returns focus to that UITextField.

Problem is I am not getting focus back to the invalid UITextField.

Here is the validation method - Why is this not putting focus back on the invalid UITextField?

Thanks!

```
//Called when form "submit" button is pressed
-(void)validateFormInput:(UITextField *)textField{
    //If Validation fails... 
    if([textField.text length] <1){ 
        //simple test case        
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        textField.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
            message:@"Please add a title"
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        alert = nil;
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];               
    }
}
```

Comment: offtopic: you're leaking a `UIAlertView`, you should add `[alert release];` after showing it.

Comment: Actually, this project is under ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add delegate to self and implement delegate method alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:. Dont forget to conform to UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.

When this method gets called make your textField first responder.